# How to concatenate variables plus os.enviorn path plus yaml in Python

Tags: python-3.x, module, operating-system, concatenation

```
1)TOPDIR =/../../

2)/ABC/path/

3)name=os.os.environ['ABC'].lower()

4).yaml
```

I want to Concatenate all four things in one like

Tried below solution :

```
[TOPDIR + "/ABC/path/" + name .yaml] appending this in Generartor
```

Not working.  Can anyone give solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TOPDIR = '/../../'
name = os.environ['ABC'].lower()
print([TOPDIR + "/ABC/PATH/" + name + '.yaml'])
```

This should work.
What's the error it throws actually?
Perhaps you have a typo "os.enviorn" should be "os.environ"

Comment: Yes it was typo mistake here.Ya ,its working Thanks.